# Designing Custom Drop Down with mulitple rows and columns

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a requirement like for the drop down as shown. Could any one help me in achieving this.

Briefing:
On click of the button a pane should be opened which contains rows and columns containing text, on click of it appropriate action need to take place. The source can be dynamic too....[image: Language drop down]

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques for acheiving this design.  You could do it purely with html and css by having an image that looks like a dropdown popup an absolutely positioned div underneath.  Or you could use the asp.net ajax control toolkit control called "[PopupControl](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx)" that essentially abstracts all the html/css away allowing you to just specify a target panel. There are also various jquery plugins, here is one from [abeatifulsite](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/).